# Firebase storage pricing questions

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

If I used firebase storage to store my videos. Say one video is 1GB, and it's viewed by 1000 users. Does it mean `GB transferred` is 1000*1GB = 1000GB? From firebase storage pricing table, I will be charged for 1000GB * $0.12/GB = $120 for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that Cloud Storage isn't a video streaming platform, so it doesn't track "views".  It only tracks egress from downloads.  So, if of the 1000 users each **download** the entire file once, and not even view it, you will be charged for a volume of 1000 * 1GB = 1000GB of egress.

The calculator on the pricing page suggests it costs $116+ for that usage.

Cloud Storage is not a very effective video *streaming* platform.  It might be more cost effective to go with a platform that only charges you for what the user actually streams while watching, rather than an entire file without even watching it.

Comment: Hmm, I heard vimeo uses GCP, is it? If so, which product in GCP provide the product that vimeo uses?

Comment: GCP refers to the entire Google Cloud Platform - all of its many products.  I'm not familar with if or how Vimeo makes used of the platform.  They have no obligation to stream content directly to people through a Cloud Storage URL.  They almost certainly have complicated streaming infrastructure in place.

Comment: Does any of the product from GCP provide video streaming service if you happen to know? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware of any.

Comment: That's ok. Thanks Doug!!!!

Comment: FYI: On Stack Overflow, it's courteous to upvote helpful answers, and also accept them as correct.

Comment: Haha, I am about to do so.